# Why does getchar() give \n even though the buffer is empty?

Tags: c, input, getchar

I have the following function that should loop and take multiple lines from the user (names and dates).
The user needs to enter an empty line to stop the loop.

```
 while ((line = getLineFromUser()) != NULL) {
    token = getNameAndDate(&concert, line);
```

however, when I get to the last line in the loop, the `getchar()` waits for the user input (which is good for me, because it means that I finished getting the previous line), but `ch` gets `'\n'` as soon as I enter the next line (not specifically an empty line). as anyone encountered this before?
Everything else seems to work fine until the last `getchar()`.
if needed, I will provide the other functions as well.

this is the  getLineFromUser function:

```
char *getLineFromUser() {
    int ch;
    char *line;

    int logSize, phySize;
    logSize = 0, phySize = 2;
    line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * phySize);
    checkAllocation(line);

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (logSize == phySize) {
            phySize *= 2;
            line = (char *)realloc(line, sizeof(char) * phySize);
            checkAllocation(line);
        }
        line[logSize] = ch;     // get char into the str
        logSize++;
    }
    if (logSize == 0) {
        free(line);
        line = NULL;
    } else {
        line = realloc(line, sizeof(char) * logSize + 1);
        checkAllocation(line);
        line[logSize] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}
```

and this is the declaration:

```
char* getLineFromUser();
```

Comment: This depends on the definition of `getLineFromUser`, which seems mysterious to me. What does it use its argument for?

Comment: because I needed to handle line by line, and didn't want to lose any chars from the buffer, I used getchar() in the main function above, checked that it's not '\n' (meaning empty line) and sended the char to the function to create a string with ch as the first char in the string, this is why the getLineFromUser gets ch as an argument

Comment: @Oka I changed my code to look like the code steve mentioned below, and inside the getLine function, I changed ch from char to int, but I still run into the same problem, I will edit my question and add the getLine function to provide more information

Comment: Yes, please provide a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that details a program we can compile, including the code that drives these functions: `main`, headers and all. The preliminary advice, in lieu of an answer,  is to use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read lines of input.

Comment: Aside: `sizeof (char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, and can be omitted from multiplicative calculations for brevity. Do not [cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2505965) (or `realloc`) in C.

Comment: @chqrlie I posted the basic idea of the code, sense it has some mallocs and other stuff

Comment: @chqrlie ok, I will change it back, just a second

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest revising your `getLineFromUser` function slightly so that you can call it more like this:

```
char *line, *token;
    
while ((line = getLineFromUser()) != NULL) {
    if(is_empty(line)) break;
    token = getNameAndDate(line);
}
```

Trying to treat the newlines separately from the lines is a recipe for complexity, confusion, and bugs.

Comment: thanks for your answer! unfortunately I still get the same problem after changing my code. I tried to handle the '\n' from the getLine function as you mentioned I should, however after the user enters a second line, the getchar() still gets a '\n' even thou the buffer is empty (I assume its empty because it awaits for my input). inside the getLine function, I loop with while(ch = getchar() != '\n' && ch != EOF)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine except for these remarks:

- `line = realloc(line, sizeof(char) * logSize + 1);` is inconsistent: you should either write `realloc(line, logSize + 1)` or `realloc(line, sizeof(char) * (logSize + 1))`. There is no consequence here since `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.
- you return `NULL` at end of file and for an empty line, so the caller cannot tell the difference. This might be a problem elsewhere in the code.

The main loop should stop as soon as an empty line is entered, or at end of file:

```
while ((line = getLineFromUser()) != NULL) {
    token = getNameAndDate(&concert, line);
}
```

You did not post the rest of the calling function: it should not have `ch = getchar();` before nor after this loop.

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help! I don't have any other functions that uses `getchar()` before or after the main while. however I tested this snippet of code on another environment and it seems to work well, for some reason it doesn't work on my environment . can it be compiler related issue?

Comment: @EliFreid: it is unlikely to be a compiler issue, but it could be a side effect of your environment's handling of user input. What environment is that?

Comment: I am using Clion on windows and on macOS, and still experience this issue

Comment: @EliFreid: how do you perform your tests? From inside Clion or from a shell prompt in a terminal window?

Comment: from inside the Clion, after some more checking it seems to be an issue with the toolchain, I will try some different toolchains and If it will sort the issue I will update

Answer (score 0):

**update:** the bug was solved.

after adding a `printf(<someString>);` inside of the main loop
it seems to have fixed the bug, I tested it with multiple strings and chars and it seems that as long as I use `printf();` it does something to "flush" the buffer and gets rid of the `\n`.

Comment: *it seems that as long as I use `printf();` it does something to "flush" the buffer and gets rid of the `\n`* Sorry to say, but that's not the way it works, so your bug isn't really fixed, and it will probably be back again some day, for as random a reason as this one.